# command line/shell paging framework/api

Tags: java, shell, command, spring-shell

I have a java command line program and I need to print a document, the document's content is very long,
so I want add-in paging function.

I want searching some framework/api who can detect the command line window size make print string adjust in windows size.

If any idea, please let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you might find [JavaHelp](https://javahelp.java.net/) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution,
Using JLine https://github.com/jline/jline2